# Do I have to specify extern "C" when exporting symbols?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am wondering if extern "C" is a must or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only if you want to call your code from C (or a different C++ compiler, which you should treat like C).

It is to disable [name-mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

See this article on the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: I am using explicit linking, without this, I found GetProcAddress failed.

Comment: @user496949: You have to use it on import for C functions, too.  The Win32 API is written in C, not C++, and thus C++ has to be told not to name-mangle to understand it.

Comment: This not only needed if you want to call code from C, but also for C++ compilers that use different name mangling.

Answer (score 1):

No, you use `extern "C"` to provide a C-linkage to your C++ functions, so they won't be 'decorated' like normal C++ functions and to allow them to be called from C (or Objective-C).

Function decoration is used to implement the C++ [function overloading](http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorials/c-tutorial-function-overloading.aspx) feature and gives each variation of the function a different signature while allowing the developer to use the name he assigned.

Your C++ functions will be exported automatically by simply not using the `static` keyword.  However if you have implemented your C++ functions within a Windows DLL it's necessary to use the `declspec dllexport/dllimport` keywords to access them externally.

Comment: In the C usage context, that might be the most prominant form of name mangling.  It is also used for a lot of other things besides overloading.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: Can you tell me what else it's used for?

Comment: Names might be mangled whether or not there are overloads.  Namespaces is another case.  For more, see the article I linked.  Again, some cases might be less relevant in the context of C linkage, but it is still used for a lot more than overloading.  Your phrasing implies that this is the only reason it is exists.  Other than that, I do like your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `extern "C"` switches off name mangling.  If you don't do this you may make if hard for a client of your DLL to import your symbols.

Remember that different C++ compilers have different name mangling rules and so your mangled exported names may differ from the names used on import.

However, since it is wrong to import a class from a DLL if you are using a different compiler than that used for the DLL, this is rather a moot point.

So, if you are exporting classes (usually a bad idea anyway) it is easier to leave mangling on. Otherwise switch it off with `extern "C"`.

Comment: +1 for exporting classes being a bad idea (except if you're using the same compiler).